# D3.js text. what is wrong in this code.

Tags: d3.js, svg, text

```
var data = [1,2,3];
```

//this code is running properly but not displaying text

```
    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('height',300).attr('width',300);

    svg.selectAll('p').data(data).enter().append('p').text("hai");
```

Comment: `<p>` elements are HTML, not SVG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG uses `text` elements, not `p` elements; try updating your second line:

```
svg.selectAll('text').data(data).enter().append('text').text("hai");
```